# Yesod fvInput can't match 'App' with 'Auth'

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I'm trying to write a custom Yesod registration form. The problem I'm having is that when it gets to fvInput it seems like it's using App instead of Auth. I'm not quite sure how this should be handled and I can't seem to find the terminology for it. I've tried lifting in various ways within the form and I can only get it to throw different errors. Also, the only time this error is thrown is if I have the fvInput line, but if I remove that no error is thrown and it compiles correctly.

Code:

```
registrationForm :: Html -> MForm (HandlerT Auth (HandlerT App IO)) (FormResult UserForm, Widget)
registrationForm extra = do
    (emailRes, emailView) <- mreq textField "" Nothing
    let userRes = UserForm <$> emailRes
    let widget = do
        [whamlet|
            #{extra}
            ^{fvInput emailView}
            <input type=Submit value="Registration">
        |]

    return (userRes, widget)
```

Error:

```
Foundation.hs:169:30:
    Couldn't match type ‘App’ with ‘Auth’
    In the second argument of ‘(GHC.Base..)’, namely ‘toWidget’
    In the expression: asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget) (fvInput emailView)
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

- Edit

Error with a lift before the mreq:

```
Foundation.hs:166:49:
   Couldn't match type ‘HandlerT Auth (HandlerT App IO)’
               with ‘transformers-0.4.2.0:Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Lazy.RWST
                       (Maybe (Env, FileEnv), HandlerSite m0, [Lang]) Enctype Ints m0’
    Expected type: HandlerT
                 Auth (HandlerT App IO) (FormResult Text, FieldView App)
      Actual type: MForm m0 (FormResult Text, FieldView App)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘mreq textField "" Nothing’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (emailRes, emailView) <- lift $ mreq textField "" Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returned `Widget` type is actually:

```
WidgetT App IO ()
```

Thus there's a mismatch between the `Widget` (which lives in just `App`) and the `emailView` (which lives in the lifted `HandlerT Auth (HandlerT App IO)` monad).

To solve this problem:

1. Change you type signature to `registrationForm :: Html -> MForm (HandlerT App IO) (FormResult UserForm, Widget)`
2. At the usage site, you'll need to employ a `lift` most likely, but after you've already called the appropriate `run` function for the form

Comment: I did try that at one point. I thought it was wrong because it was throwing another error. I'll update the post above to have the other error with lift added in. Thank you for your help!

Comment: My mistake, the lift is wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!